# Why is this use of the BIOS Disk Service Read Sector not working?

Tags: assembly, x86, bios

I'm trying to read a sector using the BIOS Disk Service Read Sectors Function but no matter what I do the carry flag is set and AH is 0x01 which means it thinks there's an invalid parameter. I've verified the registers have the content that corresponds to my partition table, which I'll also paste below. The disk image is just a normal one one created with fdisk on Arch Linux, nothing special. I'm running this in QEMU and thus this is SeaBIOS.

I even looked at the SeaBIOS code and as far as I can tell, the only way it would return an invalid parameters error would be if the count (AL) was equal to 0 or greater than or equal to 128, if the sector (i.e. CL&0x3f) were 0 or if the cylinders, heads or sectors are greater than the number of each that the disk has. None of this seems to be true as far as I can tell.
This CHS address should be (0, 32, 33) in decimal [and I'll paste a C program at the end verifying that] which should correspond to the absolute sector 2048. The last sector is (0, 65, 1) so the first sector shouldn't be out of range.
And yes, DL was 0x80, the first drive.

I'm running qemu lke this: `qemu -gdb tcp::26000 -S -hda disk.img`.

So what is going on?

```
.equ MBR_ADDRESS_RESIDENT,      0x0600  # Where the MBR will reside             
.equ MBR_ADDRESS_ORIGINAL,      0x7c00  # Where the MBR was loaded              
.equ MBR_OFFSET_PT,             0x01be  # Offset of the MBR Partition Table     
.equ MBR_OFFSET_SIGNATURE,      0x01fe  # Offset of the MBR Signature           
.equ MBR_SIZE,                  0x0200  # Size of the MBR, 512B                 
                                                                                
.equ STACK_ADDRESS,             0x8000  # at the 32KB mark                      
.equ STACK_SIZE,                0x0200  # 512B                      

    cli         # Disable interrupts                                            
                                                                                
    xor ax, ax                                                                  
    mov ds, ax                      # DS := 0x0                                 
    mov es, ax                      # ES := 0x0                                 
    mov ss, ax                      # SS := 0x0                                 
                                                                                
    mov sp, STACK_ADDRESS   # Use the 512B at 0x7e00-0x800 for the stack        
    mov bp, sp                                                                  
                                                                                
    push dx                                                                     
                                                                                
    # Relocate this MBR sector                                                  
    mov si, MBR_ADDRESS_ORIGINAL    # Where this sector is located              
    mov di, MBR_ADDRESS_RESIDENT    # Where this sector will be relocated       
    mov cx, MBR_SIZE                # The size of this sector, 512B             
    cld                                                                         
    rep movsb                                                                   
                                                                                
    sti                                                                         
                                                                                
    ljmp 0x0000, main       # Initialize the code segment register              
                                                                  


    # --- [[SNIP CODE] ---
                                                

    # SI does point to the partition table. Even hardcoding the values of DX and CX changes nothing.
    mov dx, [si+0x00]                                                           
    # DL Verified to equal 0x80                                                 
    # DH Verified to equal 0x20                                                 
    mov cx, [si+0x02]                                                           
    # CL Verified to equal 0x21                                                 
    # CH Verified to equal 0x00                                                 
    mov bx, 0x7c00              # Address to load sector                        
    mov al, 0x01                # Read one sector                               
    mov ah, 0x02                # Read Sector Function                          
    int 0x13                    # BIOS Disk Service                             
    jc error                                                               
    jmp ok
```

Here's my partition table

```
   $ dd if=disk.img of=disk.img.ptable bs=1 count=64 skip=446
   64+0 records in
   64+0 records out
   64 bytes copied, 0.000883791 s, 72.4 kB/s
   $ xxd disk.img.ptable 
   00000000: 8020 2100 0141 0100 0008 0000 0008 0000  . !..A..........
   00000010: 0041 0200 830a 0802 0010 0000 0070 0000  .A...........p..
   00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
   00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

And here's what fdisk thinks it looks like:

```
$ fdisk -l disk.img
Disk disk.img: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfdd440d0

Device     Boot Start   End Sectors Size Id Type
disk.img1  *     2048  4095    2048   1M  1 FAT12
disk.img2        4096 32767   28672  14M 83 Linux
```

Verifying the CHS address based on the values of the registers...

```
$ cat main.c 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    uint8_t
        DL = 0x80,
        DH = 0x20,  /* H */
        CL = 0x21,  /* Bits 7-6 are higher 2 bits of C,
                       Bits 5-0 are S */
        CH = 0x00;  /* Lower 8 bits of C */
    uint16_t C, H, S;

    C = CH | (((uint16_t)CL << 2) & 0x0300);
    H = DH;
    S = CL & 0x3f;
    
    printf("C/H/S = %d, %d, %d\n", C, H, S);

    return (0);
}
$ ./a.out 
C/H/S = 0, 32, 33
```

The following is how I create the disk image

```
    $ dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1M count=16
    $ dd conv=notrunc if=MBR.bin of=disk.img bs=512 count=1 seek=0
    $ printf ",1M,01\n;" | sfdisk disk.img
    $ sfdisk -A disk.img 1
```

Comment: Make sure qemu is using the geometry you expect it is. You don't seem to have posted anything about that. Also, this is not a [mcve] so we can't test.

Comment: Note that the qemu man page says heads must be less than or equal to 16 so the fact that you try 32 is very suspicious.

Comment: I added how I'm running QEMU. I don't know how to check what geometry it is using. I don't see the word 'heads' or 'geometry' in the QEMU man page so I'm not sure what you're talking about yet.

Comment: _"-hdachs c,h,s,[,t] Force hard disk 0 physical geometry (1 <= c <= 16383, 1 <= h <= 16, 1 <= s <= 63) "_

Comment: That's not in my man page (6.1.0), where are you getting this?

Comment: You can query the geometry using int 13h function 08h from the code running in qemu. I think this is supported by qemu's ROM-BIOS.

Comment: https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/about/removed-features.html  _"The geometry defined by -hdachs c,h,s,t should now be specified via -device ide-hd,drive=dr,cyls=c,heads=h,secs=s,bios-chs-trans=t"_

Comment: Jester, those are removed features. Look at the title of the page. 
Thank you ecm.

Comment: I  know. That's why I quoted it. It tells you how it should be used now. I still have an older qemu.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. I got C/H/S = 30, 15, 63. The address I'm trying to read is C/H/S = 0, 32, 33, so I think you're right. I'll see what I can do about changing QEMU's geometry or changing the disk creation procedure.

Comment: QEMU: Block format 'raw' does not support the option 'cyls'. Since version 2.26 sfdisk does not provide the --cylinders, --heads, --sectors options. I'll have to figure something else out.

Comment: Like maybe use the CHS 30,15,63 you know qemu is using? Or use LBA...

Comment: That sounds unlikely. Even if it were true, you could just use an older version of sfdisk.

Comment: Well, see the quote man page quote above for sfdisk.

Comment: @Anthony Rule of thumb, for modern disks, the geometry is usually X/15/63 where X is the largest number that makes the whole geometry fit on the disk.